# Gitlab-CI runner hangs after makefile test fails

Tags: testing, makefile, diff, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using Gitlab-CI for my build tests.  I have a very simple test which compares the output of the test install/build with the known output.  I put the test in a makefile.

The Makefile entry looks like this:

```
test:clean
    make install DESTDIR=$(TEST_DIR)
    $(TEST_DIR)/path/to/executable > $(TEST_DIR)/tmp.out
    diff test/test.result $(TEST_DIR)/tmp.out
```

When the diff passes, an exit code of 0 is returned, a exit code of 1 is returned if the diff shows a difference in the files.

What I've tried:

1. Running `make test` from any shell  runs the tests and exits, regardless of `diff` result
2. Running `make test` from the shell as  `gitlab_ci_runner` runs the tests and exists regardless of `diff` result
3. When ran from Gitlab-CI, and the `diff` exit status is 0, the build returns success

The problem:

- When ran in the Gitlab-CI and the `diff` exit status is non-0, the build hangs.
- The output on the build screen is the output of the diff, and the last line is the expected error:  `make: *** [test] Error 1`
- After that, the cycle symbol keeps on, the runner does not exit with a build fail.

Any ideas?  I thought that it might be something with Makefiles, but the Gitlab-CI will exit with a fail status if the Make exits with Error 1 for any other test.  I can only see it happening on the output of the diff.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also posted this to the GitLab mailinglist https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/gitlabhq/77e82813-b98e-4abe-9755-f39e07043384%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer